# AWS CLI 'cp' fails with "The specified bucket does not exist"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am doing my first steps with AWS and trying AWS CLI to copy a file from an EC2 server to a S3 server.

I receive an error:

> A client error (NoSuchBucket) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: The specified bucket does not exist

My command is as follows:
 - I went to my S3 dashboard, selected the bucket -> properties and copeied the 'Endpoint' value which is

> [bucket name].s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

- Then executed

> aws s3 cp ./file.ext
>   s3://[bucket name].s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/file.ext

But it failed with the error described earlier - bucket does not exist.

p.s. Running

> aws s3api list-buckets --query 'Buckets[].Name'

Shows that the bucket does exist so that isn't the issue to my understanding.

**EDIT**
If I do not use the endpoint but only use the bucket name the error message encourage to use the full name which in all the online examples seems exactly like the endpoint

> upload failed: ./file.ext to s3://[bucket name]/file.ext A client error (PermanentRedirect) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint: [bucket name].s3.amazonaws.com
>   You can fix this issue by explicitly providing the correct region location using the --region argument, the AWS_DEFAULT_REGION environment variable, or the region variable in the AWS CLI configuration file.  You can get the bucket's location by running "aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket BUCKET".

Comment: what is the name of the bucket?

Comment: Lets call it bucket_name - it is all lower case if that is what you are asking, in a form of x.com

Comment: watch out for trailing slashes

Answer (score 8):

You are using the endpoint of the bucket. Do not use that. Use the actual name of the bucket.

If you check the syntax, `bucket name` should just be the name of the bucket and not the endpoint or URL of the bucket.

```
aws s3 cp --recursive ./file.txt s3://bucketname/
```

The above error is due to a policy issue; you do not have the correct permissions for that operation. Check this guide to add policy to the AWS S3 buckets:

http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx3VRSWZ6B3SHAV/Writing-IAM-Policies-How-to-grant-access-to-an-Amazon-S3-bucket

Comment: `--recursive` seems unnecessary on a single file.

Comment: Thanks; yeah, that just worked for me without `--recursive`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the form I was trying to use did no work - see my edit - I tried to follow the recommendation and it failed.

The way I solved it meanwhile is running, as advised

> aws s3api get-bucket-location --bucket BUCKET

Then using the form of

> s3://[bucket name] --region=[return_val_of_get_bucet_location]

If anyone can advise about running without a flag I'll appreciate it.

Comment: aws-cli requires a region for most operations.  You can [set the default region](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html#cli-quick-configuration), but you always have to specify the region one way or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Please run `aws configure` command in your shell to set the default region.

You will be prompted for 4 key values. Two of them are default region and output format. The other two are keys related to access.

As user error2007s suggested use:

```
aws s3 cp file_path s3://bucket-name/path-of-object
```